# "00" becomes "0" in PHP function, but it must be "00" for RGB to work. How?

Tags: php, colors, rgb, zero

this PHP RGB brightness altering function works partially:

[image]

It misses one zero "0" at the end: so it should be "00" How to solve this?

```
$color = "#a7a709";  // constant 
$color1 = brightness($color,+25); // brighter, echoes #c0c022, correct RGB value
$color2 = brightness($color,-25); // darker echoes #8e8e0, incorrect RGB value!!
```

How to fix this?
Much appreciated!

The function brightness();

```
### CREDITS go to Cusimar9 who wrote this
function brightness($colourstr, $steps) {
  $colourstr = str_replace('#','',$colourstr);
  $rhex = substr($colourstr,0,2);
  $ghex = substr($colourstr,2,2);
  $bhex = substr($colourstr,4,2);

  $r = hexdec($rhex);
  $g = hexdec($ghex);
  $b = hexdec($bhex);

  $r = max(0,min(255,$r + $steps));
  $g = max(0,min(255,$g + $steps));  
  $b = max(0,min(255,$b + $steps));

  return '#'.dechex($r).dechex($g).dechex($b);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
```

Comment: I was thinking
`if(strlen($r) == 1)
  $r = '0'.$r;`
to bring them back to strings, and add the letter if specified, I'm a little curious now.. does sprintf use much overhead or which would be more efficient?

Comment: ... or `if ($r) < 10`... but both those seem less elegant IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but where I put those lines??

Comment: Well, sprintf is a single native function, and it only has to allocate one resulting string. I'd argue that it's more efficient.

Comment: @Sam: You just replace your `return` statement with the one I posted.

Comment: Replace the return with what he put there.

Comment: apparently you just need to substitute your return line with the one in the answer.

Comment: @EboMike You're probably right there, was just curious as I haven't used it myself.  I don't recall what language, but I remember a professor explaining to me that sprintf wasn't as good as just setting the string and handling simpler things myself, but it definitely wasn't PHP.

Comment: @Matt: That's certainly correct, but not if you're using it to do three int-to-string conversion and concatenations. At some point, the overhead of making function calls and creating temporary strings outweighs the slightly higher cost of sprintf's format parsing.

Comment: @ Oh my god it works, it works, you are geniuses, incredible guys! Thanks very much +1 to all of you jippiiieieieeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here in the comments:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

wrap each of r,g,b in the zfill/zeropad function.